# ¿Cómo ignorar celdas vacías de un archivo de excel usando la librería phpExcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

soy nuevo programando y estoy diseñando una aplicación web. Estoy trabajando con la librería de phpExcel para extraer datos de un archivo de Excel a una página web. Tengo una tabla en Excel con 6 registros pero al momento de traerlos a la pagina web me trae todas las filas de Excel. mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo ignorar las celdas vacías de Excel y que no las inserte? Aquí dejo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
$nombreArchivo = 'C:/wamp/www/formacion/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/CargaMasiva2018.xlsm';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($nombreArchivo);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(8);

$numRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(8)->getHighestRow();


echo $numRows;

echo '<table border=1> 
    <tr>
        <td> Clave </td>
        <td> Nombre Curso </td>
        <td> Clave Area </td>
        <td> Area </td>
        <td> Clasificacion </td>
        <td> Descripcion </td>
    </tr>';

for ($i=2; $i <= $numRows; $i++) { 
    $Clave = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('A'.$i)->getCalculatedValue(); 
    $NombreCurso = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('B'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $ClaveArea = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('D'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $Area = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('E'.$i)->getOldCalculatedValue();
    $Clasificacion = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('F'.$i)->getCalculatedValue();
    $Descripcion = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('G'.$i)->getOldCalculatedValue();


        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$Clave.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$NombreCurso.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$ClaveArea.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$Area.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$Clasificacion.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$Descripcion.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';



        $sql = "INSERT INTO curso (idcurso, nombre_curso, clave_area_curso, area_curso, clasificacion_curso, descripcion_curso) VALUE('$Clave', '$NombreCurso', '$ClaveArea', '$Area', '$Clasificacion', '$Descripcion')";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);


        mysql_close($mysqli);


}

echo '</table>';
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, verifica si el valor es nullo `if($objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('G'.$i)->getOldCalculatedValue() == null){//.....` de esa manera verificas si una celda contiene valores o no, esa librería esta depreciada, verifica en su web oficial el enlace a la nueva librería.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, Carlos Quintero. ¡Entendido! pero después de conocer si el campo es null, como puedo hacer que el programa lo ignore? Eh estado pensando en un ciclo While pero, como mencioné, soy nuevo prgramando.

Answer (score 1):

ok SI estas leyendo un archivo con muchas lineas debes ejecutar un bucle y donde asignas las variables indicar el valor por defecto su el campo es nulo, por ejemplo:

```
$con = 0;
$i=0;
while($con<=0){
    $Descripcion = ($objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('G'.$i)->getOldCalculatedValue()==null) ? 'Valor por defecto' : $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('G'.$i)->getOldCalculatedValue();

    //Cortamos la mjestra de filas si se llega a la última
    if($objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Catalogo cursos')->getCell('G'.$i)->getOldCalculatedValue()==null){
        $con=1;
    }
    $i++;
    //Aqui va la muestra de las filas
}
```

Recuerda usar una celda para controlar el corte del bucle, una celda que sepas que va a tener datos de manera obligatoria o de o contrario podrias cortar el bucle sin mostrar todas las filas.